# British airways BA256 - BA376 Transit requirement

Tags: british-airways

I am traveling from New Delhi IGI Airport to Blagnac Airport Toulouse via Heathrow London, I would be boarding my flight at 10.20 am from India which will drop me at Toulouse at 20.35 with a 5-hour layover at Heathrow. I am going on a student visa, do i require an airport transit visa. If so please assist me how to apply for transit visa.